# Java Codelab New line

Tags: java

How do I make my output like the one that is expected? To make it more clear, how do I make it so that the output "It·will·take9.090909090909091E-4·seconds" is on the same line as everything else and not a new line?

Expected Output:

Enter·one·of·the·following:·air,·water,·or·steel:·Enter·the·distance·the·sound·wave·will·travel:··It·will·take·9.090909090909091E-4·seconds.↵

Actual Output:

Enter·one·of·the·following:·air,·water,·or·steel:·Enter·the·distance·the·sound·wave·will·travel:↵
·It·will·take9.090909090909091E-4·seconds.

LEGEND OF SPECIAL SYMBOLS:
Symbol  Meaning
·   Space Char
↵   Newline (\n)
→   Tab (\t)
←   Carriage Return (\r)

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Scanner for input
//Class name
public class TESTTEST
{
public static void main(String[] args)//main section
{
    //varibles
    String speed;
    double distance;
    double time;
    //set scanner
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //ask for the type of speed input
    System.out.println("Enter one of the following: air, water, or steel: "
            +"Enter the distance the sound wave will travel:");
    speed = keyboard.nextLine();
    distance = keyboard.nextDouble();
    if (speed.equals("air") || speed.equals("water") || speed.equals("steel"))

     //set switch
     switch (speed)
     {

        case "air":
           time = distance/1100;
           System.out.print(" It will take" + time + " seconds.");
           break;
        case "water":
           time = distance/4900;
           System.out.print(" It will take" + time + " seconds.");
           break;
        case "steel":
           time = distance/16400;
           System.out.print(" It will take" + time + " seconds.");
           break;
         default:System.out.print("Sorry, you must enter air,water,or steel.");

}
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use `println()` if you don't want the newline.  e.g. `System.out.println("Enter one of the following:...` should be `System.out.print("Enter one of the following:...`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, even `System.out.print("Enter one of the following ...);` won't work, because you are using `Scanner` and expecting input from the user. After the input is entered, the user needs to press the `ENTER` key of the keyboard to hand the control over to the program, this will produce `new line` in the console.